# Cannot update Craft, only download the zip

Tags: updates

Recently I cannot update Craft on a server. From versions 2.6.2778 and 2.6.2779. I only can download the zip to install it myself. What could be wrong here? 
Thanks in advance.

PHP: 5.6.16-1byte1

Alert on iconv (older version)

Answer (score 3):

You can do manual installs easily, all you really need it's the app folder inside the craft folder. but don't just replace it.
I would rename the new app folder to something like "app-new" move it next to the other app folder inside craft folder. once it is all done copying. I would rename the "app" folder into "app-old" and rename the "app-new" into "app" again. Then go to your admin URL and craft should do the automatic database changes that it needs. It has worked for me in the past and it's quick and easy and less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But why do I get a Download button instead of Update button?

Comment: There's many reasons why that happens, I would check the logs why that happens, my experience is because of server permissions, make sure the www group has permissions to write on the specific folder and you are not using a different owner/group when uploading files. EG. people like using root credentials to upload files. that means those folders are root/root for permissions. and when trying to do auto update apache doesn't have root level permissions.